# Qt - What are Sample Buffers?

Tags: qt, opengl, buffer, qt4.7

I am learning the basics of OpenGL with Qt and it seems sample buffers are Qt specific, and I don’t really understand what information they store for the screen. What is a Sample Buffer and what is it used for?

Comment: What do you mean by "sample buffers"?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

They are used to get [multisampling](http://www.opengl.org/wiki/Multisampling) in Qt. Setting up multisampling is normally platform specific (since it requires a pixel format with multisampling support), but Qt lets you do this in a platform independent way. To get a OpenGL context with multisampling you pass a [QGLFormat](http://doc.qt.digia.com/stable/qglformat.html) with sample buffers enabled when creating your QGLWidget.

Specifically, [QGLFormat::setSampleBuffers](http://doc.qt.digia.com/stable/qglformat.html#setSampleBuffers) is used to request a multisampled context and [QGLFormat::setSamples](http://doc.qt.digia.com/stable/qglformat.html#setSamples) is used to set the prefered number of samples.

In your OpenGL code you also have to enable multisampling before rendering:

```
glEnable(GL_MULTISAMPLE);
```

Comment: Actually, `GL_MULTISAMPLE` is enabled by default in the GL, it just has no effect until a multisampled framebuffer is in use.